# How to determine which TextField triggered EventHandler in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, eventhandler

I have 3 fields:

```
@FXML
private TextField name;

@FXML
private TextField lastName;

@FXML
private TextField phoneNumber;
```

I created for them `EventHandler`:

```
 EventHandler<InputEvent> fieldChangeListener = new EventHandler<InputEvent>() {
            public void handle(InputEvent event) {
                String input = ((TextField) event.getSource()).getText();
                System.out.println("Changed: "+event.getSource());
                event.consume();
            }
        };
```

And assigned to them:

```
name.addEventHandler(InputMethodEvent.INPUT_METHOD_TEXT_CHANGED, fieldChangeListener);
lastName.addEventHandler(InputMethodEvent.INPUT_METHOD_TEXT_CHANGED, fieldChangeListener);
phoneNumber.addEventHandler(InputMethodEvent.INPUT_METHOD_TEXT_CHANGED, fieldChangeListener);
```

How can I determine which one of my 3 fields triggered event? 
I want to call different functions depending on which one of those was changed, like:-

```
if(name){
function changedName();
}
else if(lastName){
function changedLastName();
}
 else if(phoneNumber){
function changedPhoneNumber();
}
```

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use 3 different event handlers instead of trying to squeeze the logic for all 3 fields into a single handler. Also why don't you use a method to handle these events and use the `onInputMethodTextChanged` attribute in the fxml to register the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting one event handler on all of them, create 3 different handlers

```
EventHandler<InputEvent> nameChangedHandler = (event) -> changedName();
EventHandler<InputEvent> lastNameChangedHandler = (event) -> changedLastName();
EventHandler<InputEvent> phoneNumberChangedHandler = (event) -> changedPhoneNumber();
```

and then then add them to their respective `TextField`s. If you are using a single event handler because there is common code at the start and end, then simply refactor those into separate functions and call them in all the event handlers.

If you still need an explicit check then use

```
Object source = event.getSource();
if(source == name) {
    changedName();
} else if(source == lastName) {
    changedLastName();
} else if(source == phoneNumber) {
    changedPhoneNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextField input = ((TextField) event.getSource());
input.getId();
```